# Use ActiveRecord scope in ActiveAdmin filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin

In my rails project I have model :

```
class Panel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :surveys

  scope :by_survey_name, ->(survey_name) {
    joins(:surveys).where('surveys.survey_name LIKE (?)', "%#{survey_name}%")
  }
end
```

And the question is how can I use this scope in activeadmin fiter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add to model:

```
  def self.ransackable_scopes(_auth_object = nil)
    [:by_survey_name]
  end
```

and then in resource:

```
  filter :by_survey_name, as: :string
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work anymore (missing method `by_survey_name_contains' for Ransack::Search). Is this really the proper way to create filters with scopes ? Is there any documentation for that somewhere ?

Comment: I have had this issue in the past (missing "_contains") in which case the solution was to rename the scope with "_in" at the end to bypass some logic. But at the moment I tested a similar model and ":by_survey_name" works for me as-is.  AAv2.9.0, Rails 6.0.3.7

Answer (score 0):

Scopes need to be enabled explicitly: https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/going-further/other-notes/#using-scopesclass-methods

A string filter expects multiple scopes, such as `contains`, `equals`, `starts_with`, `ends_with`.

```rb
class Panel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :surveys

  scope :survey_name_contains, ->(survey_name) {
    joins(:surveys).where('surveys.survey_name LIKE (?)', "%#{survey_name}%")
  }
  scope :survey_name_equals, ...
  scope :survey_name_starts_with, ...
  scope :survey_name_ends_with, ...

  def self.ransackable_scopes(_auth_object = nil)
    [:by_survey_name, :survey_name_equals, :survey_name_starts_with, :survey_name_ends_with]
  end
end
```

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Panel do
  filter :survey_name, as: :string
end
```

Alternatively, you can name the filer `survey_name_in`:

```rb
class Panel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :surveys

  scope :survey_name_in, ->(survey_name) {
    joins(:surveys).where('surveys.survey_name LIKE (?)', "%#{survey_name}%")
  }

  def self.ransackable_scopes(_auth_object = nil)
    [:survey_name_in]
  end
end
```

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Panel do
  filter :survey_name_in, as: :string, label: 'Survey name'
end
```

Verified on `activeadmin 2.13` and `rails 7.0`.