# Use ActiveRecord scope in ActiveAdmin filter -- only apply the filter if checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ransack

I have an `ActiveRecord` class `Foo` and I have an ActiveAdmin index view listing all my foos. 
 `Foo` has a scope called `bland` and my UI requirement is that I have a checkbox in the **Filters** section so that I can see all the bland foos.

I.e., I'd like the **Filters** section to look like this:

[image]

I have read through questions and blogs like the following that say I need a custom ransacker:

[Use ActiveRecord scope in ActiveAdmin filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694398/use-activerecord-scope-in-activeadmin-filter)

So my code is something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foo
  filter :bland, label: 'Bland Foos', as: :check_boxes, collection: ['exclude tasty']
end

class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  scope :bland, -> { where("tasty < 3") }
  def self.ransackable_scopes(_auth_object = nil)
    [:bland]
  end
end
```

However, when I try to run this I get an error like:

> undefined method `bland_in' for #Ransack::Search:0x00007f8d18e61db8

Ouch.

As an experiment I tried something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foo
  filter :bland, label: 'Bland Foos'
end

class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  scope :bland, -> (dummy_param_not_used) { where("tasty < 3") }
  def self.ransackable_scopes(_auth_object = nil)
    [:bland]
  end
end
```

My idea here being:  ok, ActiveAdmin will put up a string input and we'll fill in a value just to trigger the code ... but then the filter doesn't even show on my UI!

Comment: Should that be collection: [['exclude', false], ['tasty',true]] ?

Comment: Hm ... maybe it would be `[['exclude tasty'],true]` meaning that I want to have "exclude tasty" as the text.  I'll update the question to include a screenshot.  Though I tried this and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

See if this can be of any use. You can change UI elements if required.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foo
  ......
  scope :bland, -> { where("tasty < 3") }
  ......
end
```

Reference : [ActiveAdmin Documentation](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html#index-scopes)

Answer (score 1):

One way to easily resolve that issue is adding suffix

> _in

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foo
  filter :bland, label: 'Bland Foos'
end

class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  scope :bland_in, -> (dummy_param_not_used) { where("tasty < 3") }
  def self.ransackable_scopes(_auth_object = nil)
    [:bland_in]
```